# Assign random background images to Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, image, panel

I'm trying to assign random images to a panel:

```
System.Random randomNum = new System.Random();
int myInt = randomNum.Next(4);

if (Panel1.BackgroundImage != null)
{
    switch (myInt)
    {
        case 0:
            Panel1.BackgroundImage = @"C:\Users\etrit.bujupi\Desktop\IO-Etrit\CardGame\Images\2-Black.jpg";
    }
}
```

But my code causes an error:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Image'

Comment: What CAN you do? I mean, can you add panels, can you add graphics, do you know there is a [RANDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.random.aspx) class? -1  as we need more details as it reads as if you want us to write the game for you!

Comment: @DaveRook I'm a rookie. Btw the panels are in the form, I just need to give them random images.

Comment: I'm not trying to sound rude (I am trying to help), but, this site isn't there for people to do your work, we're here to help if you get stuck. My advice is just try to add an image, and then images. And then see how to randomise an array of images (or however you approach it) and ask at specific points when you get stuck, with examples of your code!

Comment: @DaveRook I used Panel1.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(youtpath); 
as Shaharyar answered below. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: yeah, so many answers I won't bother! Also, don't forget to mark the answer as Answer! :) I'm glad you got it working and hope my comments helped to write a better question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code might get you on the way:

```
ImageList images = new ImageList();
images.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\\pic1.bmp"));
images.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\\pic2.bmp"));
//Fill with more images

//Make a Random-object
Random rand = new Random();
// This could also be a panel already on the Form
Panel p = new Panel(); 

//Pick a random image from the list
p.BackgroundImage = images.Images[rand.Next(0, images.Images.Count - 1)];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
Panel1.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(yourPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Random randomNum = new System.Random();
        int myInt = randomNum.Next(4);

        if (Panel1.BackgroundImage != null)
        {
            switch (myInt)
            {
                case 0:
                    Panel1.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile( @"C:\Users\etrit.bujupi\Desktop\IO-Etrit\CardGame\Images\2-Black.jpg");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

Add the image in your project resources, then use it like that:

```
Panel1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.MyImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

An updated solution, using existing VS2022 features:

- Design your windows form and System.Drawing.Form object necessary to display an image from a file
- Go to Project --> Properties --> Resources and add all your images using the Add Resource
- Visual Studio will automatically add the code into the Resources.resx and Resources.Designer.cs files. DO NOT EDIT THESE BY HAND.
- Inside your custom Designer, go to View Code and add the following:

  ```
   Random rand = new Random();
   int rnd = rand.Next(0, 3);  //random number from 0 to 3 (4 images in my case)
   switch (rnd)
   {
       case 0:
           this.BackgroundImage = global::myProject.Properties.Resources.image1;
           break;
       case 1:
           this.BackgroundImage = global::myProject.Properties.Resources.image2;
           break;
       case 2:
           this.BackgroundImage = global::myProject.Properties.Resources.image3;
           break;
       case 3:
           this.BackgroundImage = global::myProject.Properties.Resources.image4;
           break;
   }
  ```

Where 'image1, 2 etc' are your named image reference names.

Should work.